# Convert JSON output of Facebook page likes into PHP string

Tags: php, json, facebook

so I am able to use the following url to get a JSON object with the number of Facebook likes for a particular page. But I am struggling to do anything with the data - how could I use the returned number as a PHP variable?

URL: https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20like_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%27https://www.facebook.com/%27&format=json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use json_decode for that (see : http://docs.php.net/json_decode)

```
<?php
$json_url = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20like_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%27https://www.facebook.com/%27&format=json";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$json = json_decode($json, true);

print_r($json);

echo "Number of likes : " . $json[0]['like_count'];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are being returned a JSON string, in order to use this data in PHP you convert it to its PHP equivalent data type using the [`json_decode()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), like this :_

```
<?php
$json_string = file_get_contents('http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20like_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%27https://www.facebook.com/%27&format=json');

$json = json_decode($json_string);
echo json_last_error_msg().PHP_EOL;

echo $json[0]->like_count;
```